# Where does DeepBlueAdmin\shield-ui Theme get's the data from?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, shieldui

I downloaded  and tested out the "Deep Blue Admin A dashboard / bootstrap admin theme in the blue color set"   from: `http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-theme/deepblue-admin`,  when I opened  the index.html plage i saw that data is populated there, but didn't see where this data is coming from

Answer (score 1):

The data is coming from :  gridData.js

in the header of the html file there's a row:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/js/gridData.js"></script>
```

to make a local copy - get the file and place it in your local computer. Don't forget to update the "src" in the HTML file to the new location on your computer, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data/Content/js/gridData.js"></script>
```